# How do I automatically size UI elements using Xamarin Studio (or MS Visual Studio for Xamarin) layout for iOS?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, layout, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I've been trying to create a layout on an iOS app using Xamarin Studio (I've recently switched to Microsoft Visual Studio with Xamarin) and I want it to automatically resize the buttons so it will look the same on all sizes of devices.

The layout manager in iOS allows this as I understand it, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it visually from within the IDE.

I know how to do it programerically so please don't give answers that involve code unless the result allows for visual layout (such as a custom control or whatever.)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In xamarin studio you have to do it under the whatever activity.cs buttonstyle code.

Comment: Are you able to use Xcode's Interfacebuilder? as you can add more complex contraints using this.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Auto Layout you can specify the constraints using the Xamarin Designer for iOS in Visual Studio.

First of all you will need to enable Auto Layout for your storyboard by checking the `Use Autolayout` checkbox in the properties panel.

After that you can use Constraint Toolbar to manage the constraints.

[image: Constraint Toolbar]

You can also use drag and drop to setup the constrains between different elements:

[image]

You can view full details at [Auto Layout with the Xamarin Designer for iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/designer_auto_layout/)

Comment: Yes, I know about Auto Layout.  I should've been more precise in my question.  What I want is particularly having to set the size.  I can set the size to the size of another button, but what I need is to do something like set the size to a percentage of the parent object.  This is to make the buttons grow or shrink with the size of the screen.

Comment: @DavidMesser: So what is your question?